# Is it legal for my employer (UK) to ask personal questions?

Tags: human-resources, united-kingdom, security, privacy

My employer in the United Kingdom has been requested by a third party (whom we, the company, work for) that all employees complete a security related interview involving personal questions such as if we have any issues in our marriage, if we have any problems with car/house loans etc., If we have problems with alcohol or drugs outside of work and other personal questions.

This is for the benefit of the 3rd party company and was not mentioned in our original contract unless there is a catchall clause covering it. We have all worked here for more than 3 years.

The answers will be recorded with a summary sent to the 3rd party confidentially and records kept confidentally by our HR department at our company.

Is this legal in the UK? There has been an implication that it wouldn't be acceptable to refuse to answer questions.

Comment: Is this for security clearance? Or a security audit by a customer?

Comment: security clearance but im not sure which one specifically

Comment: I work for my employer. Whom we work for, as in we the company, work for the 3rd party. But they are not my employer.

Comment: Have the company  said what the vetting is ?? This sounds like DV the highest Level of vetting for defence work.

Comment: I am sure that I was asked similar questions for SC, not DV. They certainly wanted to know my nett worth. Btw, @Bilkokuya, you *should* post that as an answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They can *ask* but you have every right to tell them to shove it.

This isn't normal in any shape or form, the sorts of questions you are talking about do get looked into to one degree or another when you're going through some of the more rigorous security clearances and while I've had third parties require clearances to work with them before you don't provide this information directly to the third party or even to your employer but instead to the UKSV who will only tell the employer/third party a cleared or not-cleared status.

Comment: thanks, the third party is not based within the UK which may make a difference?

Comment: @Steven it might make a difference - particularly if we are talking about a non-EU country?

Comment: its an EU country

Comment: I like the point that you should be providing this information to an appropriate entity. If you were working with a third party that required vaccinations before a visit to a medical facility, would your HR department give you the shots?

Answer (score 7):

If you needed some government security clearance, then an awful lot of question would be asked, your family and maybe your friends would be asked, but your employer would not hear anything about anything you say, except at the end whether you got clearance or not.

So your employer asking for that kind of information is a very, very dark crimson red flag. They can ask, but they have not the slightest rights to an answer.

Comment: Family & friends only get asked for DV, the highest UK clearance level, but not for SC, which is the commonest

Answer (score 5):

> all employees complete a security related interview involving personal questions such as if we have any issues in our marriage, if we have any problems with car/house loans etc., If we have problems with alcohol or drugs outside of work and other personal questions.

These questions generally fall into security clearance type questions for government jobs. However, for private sector I do not feel the questions are appropriate unless you work in some sensitive job like a bank. You can refuse to answer but you may not get selected for the job. As for legality of the questions, that's something you have to find out with a lawyer. Nobody here can say for sure if these are protected questions. Since they do ask it, I would imagine they are legal questions.